# TENSORFLOW :How to use tf.stop_gradient( or how to stop gradients from flowing)when creating custum gradients using pyfunc and gradient overide?

Tags: tensorflow

Hi i am creating my custom gradients for a new op that i have created using py_func and have overridden those gradients using gradient override and tf.register_gradient method in tensorflow.

```
def fp(input1,input2,input3,input4):
        Forward_pass = *do stuff with all inputs*
        return Forward_pass


def py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=None, grad=None):
                rnd_name = 'PyFuncGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8)) 
                tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)
                g = tf.get_default_graph()
                with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": rnd_name}):

                      return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)

def Forward_pass(input1,input2,input3,input4, name='fp'):

    with ops.op_scope([input1,input2,input3,input4]) as name:

        alpha = py_func(fp,
                        [input1,input2,input3,input4],
                        [tf.float32],
                        name=name,
                        grad=_MyGrads) 

        return alpha

# Actual gradient:
def _MyGrads(op, grad):
***
    do stuff with op.input[0],op.input[1],op.input[2],op.input[3]
    to get grad1,grad2,grad2  
    *****
return None*grad,grad1*grad,grad2*grad,grad3*grad
`
```

However the number of inputs in my op are 4 and it requires 4 gradients. But i want only 3 gradients, and tensorflow requires the number of gradients to be the same as that of number of inputs when defining own gradient.

To solve this issue i have tried a few tricks but none worked:
1.use tf.stop_gradient for the input whose gradient i dont want lets say "input1".
2.Return zeros 
3.Return None which says None values not supported.

For 1 and 2 i am getting shape error in back prop where tensorflow is trying to apply gradients of the "input1" , which of a different shape ,
 on other inputs.
 I get this error:
`InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 16777216 values, but the requested shape has
4096
         [[Node: gradients/truediv_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0
/device:GPU:0"](gradients/truediv_grad/Sum, gradients/truediv_grad/Shape)]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, changing None * grad to None solved the issue
`

```
def _MyGrads(op, grad):
***
    do stuff with op.input[0],op.input[1],op.input[2],op.input[3]
    to get grad1,grad2,grad2  
    *****
return None,grad1*grad,grad2*grad,grad3*grad`
```